# Best place to do sanitise PHP form data

Tags: php, security, sanitization

I have a `Menu` class which is responsible for UPDATE and GET. In this class I take the data from POST request iterate over and do some additional processing before I save. visa versa when returning the menu. As I iterate over data, I also do sanitisation of individual menu item object.

```
// menu.php

class Menu {

 private $menu;

 public function __construct( $menuItems) {
   $this->menu = $menuItems;
 }

 public function getMenu() {
    return self::processMenuForRender($this->menu);

    // $processMenuForRender 
  }

  public function updateMenu($data) {
    $processedMenu = self::processMenuForRender();

    // $processMenuForRender 
  }

  private function processMenuForRender($data) {
    foreach ($data as $item) {
      // process data recursively
      // sanitise $item
      $sanitisedItem = self::sanitiseMenu($item);
    }

    return $processedDataJSONObject
  }

  private function processMenuForSave($data) {
    foreach ($data as $item) {
      // process data
      // sanitise $item

      $sanitised = self::sanitiseMenu($item);
    }

        return $processedDataArray
  }

  private function sanitiseItem($item) {
    return array(
        'linkText' => filter_var($item['linkText'], FILTER_VALIDATE_String),
        'id' => filter_var($item['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE),
    )
  }
}
```

I then use this class at some other place e.g. `MainPage`

```
// mainpage.php
class MainPage {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->menu = new Menu();
    }

    public function renderMenu() {
        return $this->menu->getMenu();
    }


    public function updateMenu() {
        // get POST data
        $this->menu->updateMenu($_POST['menu']);
    }
}
```

Then I instantiate `mainpage.php` in `app.php`

```
// app.php
 <?php echo ( new MainPage() )->renderMenu(); ?>
<form action='/mainpage.php' method='post'>
 // Fields to update the menu 
</form>
```

So question is am I putting sanitisation in correct place? And given that both `menu.php` and `mainpage.php` are still accessible by typing `www.mywebsite.com/somepage/mainpage.php` `www.mywebsite.com/somepage/menu.php`. can someone just call `new Menu -> public updateMenu` or `new Menu -> public getMenu` method and bypass sanitation checks I've implemented? If the answer is yes how can I prevent it?

Comment: "am I putting sanitisation in correct place?"  Well, I don't see anything resembling MVC so no / it doesn't matter since you made up everything else?

Comment: @AlexBarker I am sorry, I am not 100% sure if I understand your point. However, I just updated the question. I am not using any MVC framework. I have very basic PHP knowledge. Yes I've had to simplify the code I've put here.

Comment: Because you are not using an established design pattern, it doesn't matter where you put the sanitation.  I usually put validation in or around the controller, but you don't have one so.... put it where ever you want.

Comment: @AlexBarker ok.... but what about this part? ` can someone just call `new Menu -> public updateMenu` or `new Menu -> public getMenu` methods and bypass sanitation checks I've implemented?

Comment: Well both those methods call the sanitize function you created, so not really, no. Rule of thumb would be to fail fast on validation errors before doing a bunch of work, and escape stuff like SQL when you perform the action that requires an escape.  For XSS stuff, escape/strip before insert so you don't need to do it over and over.

Comment: @AlexBarker I am rendering/posting json object. So I can't really for e.g. validate particular value types e.g. strings, int? Are you suggesting that I should escape `JSON.stringified` post data only? or do that at the earliest opportunity before I iterate over data to sanitise/validate property value types?

Comment: Use Json Schema to validate your json with a library and save yourself a ton of headaches.  Then you can just json_decode to and object and pass it around.